# Why AuthenticationManager is throwing StackOverflowError?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am getting `StackOverflowError` while calling `authenticationManger.authenticate()`

> java.lang.StackOverflowError: null    at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jLog.isDebugEnabled(LogAdapter.java:300)
>   ~[spring-jcl-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:162)
>   ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503)
>   ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]

I am trying to implement JWT in my application. I have created `JWTTOkenUtil`, Filter, Controller. But only Authentication manager is not working. I have tried with `CustomAuthenticationManger` as well but same error.

File `AppConfig.java`

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public class AppConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailService jwtUserDetailService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider);

     //auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/version").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter() {
            return new JwtRequestFilter();
    }
}
```

Comment: `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503` line number `delegate.authenticate(authentication);` where delegate  is declared as `private AuthenticationManager delegate;` And you have not given complete logs, even not good formatted logs. But in logs i didn't see null pointer, but it shows `java.lang.StackOverflowError: null at` this much i can figure out. As you have not provided code of `JwtAuthenticationProvider` question seems to be have incomplete information.

Comment: You could just not override `AuthenticationManager authenticationManager()` method. `authenticationManager()` and `authenticationManagerBean()` of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` are two different methods, and you are calling `authenticationManagerBean()` method of your `super` class, which, as far as I know, depends on `authenticationManager()` method. This, in return creates a cyclic calls of methods.

Comment: @Hasan exactly that will be source of stack overflow error. authenticationManager method should return an implementation of AuthenticationManager by overriding authenticate method.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I should call super method of what i am overriding. either authenticateManager() or authenticateManagerBean().

Comment: @HasanCanSaral you should post as an answer for acknowledgement.  Often times comments go unread by those skimming for the selected/upvoted answer.  Your explanation helped me with the same issue.  Thanks

Comment: @Floresj4 You're right, I just didn't know if it helped to the OP. Just in case, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`authenticationManager()` and `authenticationManagerBean()` of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` are two different methods, and you are calling authenticationManagerBean() method of your super class, which, as far as I know, depends on `authenticationManager()` method. This, in return creates a cyclic calls of methods, which finally results in `StackOverflowError` exception.

You could try just not override `AuthenticationManager authenticationManager()` method, or return a solid implementation when doing so.

Answer (score 2):

You are overiding the wrong method authenticationManager(), it should be authenticationManagerBean() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead overriding authenticationManager() method, you need to override authenticationManagerBean() method of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class.

This is a working configuration for me.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```