# StackOverflowError while using authenticationManager.authenticate() method

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am getting `StackOverflowError` while using `authenticationManger.authenticate()`. I see question already answered here: [Why AuthenticationManager is throwing StackOverflowError?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58598448/15066764), but im not extending deprecated `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, so my configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig{

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().disable().csrf().disable().sessionManagement()
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable();
        http
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(0)
    public SecurityFilterChain resources(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers((matchers) -> matchers.antMatchers("*.bundle.*"))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll())
                .requestCache().disable()
                .securityContext().disable()
                .sessionManagement().disable();

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

And i still get

```
2022-07-18 17:26:52.277 ERROR 12368 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor60.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor60.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor60.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]

*continues till stack overflow*
```

Current version of `AuthenticationManager` bean i borrowed here (in comment section): [spring.io docs](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)

Im using `AuthenticationManager` in my controller to manually authentificate users:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    CustomUserService userService;

    @Autowired
    JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<Object, Object>> login(@RequestBody CustomUserLoginDto userDto) {
        try {
            String email = userDto.getEmail();
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, userDto.getPassword()));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(email);
            Map<Object, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
            model.put("username", email);
            model.put("token", token);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(model);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid email/password supplied");
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public CustomUser register(@RequestBody CustomUserCreateDto userDto) {
        return userService.saveUser(userDto);
    }
}
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: I vaguely remember running into something similar when converting from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. What happens if you remove the AuthenticationManager bean?

Comment: @LeeGreiner, nothing for the whole security system, but i want to use this bean in controller, so i must define it. If there is another method to define it, id like to know that too, thanks

Comment: Why do you need the `AuthenticationManager` in the controller? Can you describe the request and maybe debug the `FilterChainProxy` and find the filter that is causing the stack overflow?

Comment: Behind the scenes is an AuthenticationManagerBuilder. My guess is that an AuthenticationManager bean is available in your controller but I would have to ask why you need it in your controller.

Comment: @LeeGreiner added related info, see question

Comment: Try commenting out the AuthenticationManager in your config. I believe one is being created for you.

Comment: @LeeGreiner im getting missing bean failure, thats the point i started looking for that definition. I dont know why this bean is not defined by default as it should be

Comment: Its not defined because he has opted out of using any of the built in standardized login schemas and instead built a custom security solution which is normally bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to replace your login method with a custom filter which is extending `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    protected AuthenticationFilter() {
        super("/login");
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

        if (!request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(HttpMethod.POST.name())) {
            return null;
        }

        // extract login and password
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login, password));

    }

}
```

To access `AuthenticationManager` you should use custom DSL ([Accessing the local AuthenticationManager](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter))

```
public class CustomDsl extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<CustomDsl, HttpSecurity> {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
        http.addFilterAfter(authenticationFilter(authenticationManager), ConcurrentSessionFilter.class);
    }

    public AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        final AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new AuthenticationFilter();
        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler());
        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        return authenticationFilter;
    }

    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }

    public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

}
```

then apply it

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // ...
    http.apply(customDsl());
    return http.build();
}
```

and remove this from your config

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue in my spring boot microservice example. As I still couldn't fix the issue, it is possible to help me? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74633891/spring-boot-microservices-servicetest-and-controllertest-for-junit-throwing-ja

Comment: just removing authentication manager bean made the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new CustomUserDetailsService();
}
```

This code is redundant, you just need to inject the class implementing the UserDetailsService interface into the IOC container.